# Connect two servers locally via 10Gb switch

Tags: linux, networking, local-area-network

I have two linux servers on a rack both connected to my company network. Each contain 10+ TB of storage. Both servers can mount the others storage array over the network as it exists. However, I have noticed we have a 10Gb switch on the server rack that is completely unused. And each server has an additional unused ethernet port.

My question is: would there be any measurable benefit in data transfer speeds between these two servers by connecting them to each other locally through this switch?

If so, could you point me in the direction of how accomplish this task? I cannot find anything by googling so I am afraid I may not be using to correct terminology to find the result I am after.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your servers will need 10Gb NICs on them in order to take advantage of any additional speed. You can team the additional NIC to get redundancy, or to take any transfer traffic off of your main network, but you won't be able to pull more than 1Gb (minus overhead) on any single connection.

Configuring the 10Gb NICs is no different than configuring 1Gb NICs.

If you want to make sure that the two servers talk to each other only over the link through the 10Gb switch, you need to create a network for them to do so on. Depending on the switch config, you'll either need to setup a VLAN, or just add these two servers into the existing network on that switch, and then make sure that DNS for both is resolving to the IP on that subnet, not the one on your main one. Probably you'll need to do that with a hosts file edit, not regular DNS resolution.

However, as 10Gb switches are generally used only for important traffic, you should really investigate if this is actually what you need to do, or if you're only doing it because you can.

If you're just looking to connect the two servers directly, you may be better off just directly connecting them, and not running through the switch at all. Set up a small network (/30) and configure the two to talk to each other through that.

All of this can involve some advanced networking tasks which shouldn't be undertaken unless there's an actual need to do so, and honestly, shouldn't be done on a production system by anyone other than a senior networking person.

Comment: I believe your last sentence is really my question I am looking for. Can you point me to information about configuing the second NIC of each server to communicate with each other locally through the switch while still keeping their connection as-is to the company network?

Comment: But it should be noted that the OP could bond the nics together, to get 2Gb/s (assuming the network cards contain 1gbs nics).

Comment: @DavidW bonding the connection via LACP or some such will give a total link speed of 2Gb, but will not allow any single traffic stream/connection to acheive more than the top speed of either NIC in the team.

Comment: Correct. I suppose having a 10Gbps switch doesn't make a difference in that case, unless you had multiple connections from different users / devices, and/or a connection with a device that did have a 10gbps NIC.

Comment: @Anthony without a lot more information about what kind of traffic you're hoping to pass, how the applications that use that traffic are configured, how your existing internal network is configured, and how the switch is configured, I can't offer anything other than generic advice. I'll add that to my answer shortly.